# Add URL Rewrite Rule To Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've written a Wordpress plugin that adds a query string to the URL. However I can't seem to modify the htaccess to rewrite this. Not sure if Wordpress is overriding it?

The current htaccess is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And the URL I'm trying to rewrite is:

```
http://domain.com/deal-info/?id=87&post_name=testdealtitle
```

Desired URL:

```
http://domain.com/deal-info/87/testdealtitle
```

I've tried adding:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /deal-info/?id=$1&post_name=$2 [L]
```

to no avail. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: What application handles this request `http://domain.com/deal-info/87/testdealtitle`: is the the WordPress `index.php` or some other php file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much confusion I found an answer here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule

Though I think the proper way to do it is by:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

I'm not sure if you can do this directly in htaccess, or I was having a conflict problem with another plugin I was using.

Thanks again to Olivier for his extensive answer!

Answer (score 17):

When you do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This means: "if it's not a file, and if it's not a dir, redirect **all** incoming URLs to 
**`index.php`**.

Your rewriterule should work... unless you've put it **after** the previous rewriterule. So, in short, are you sure your .htaccess it like that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /deal-info/?id=$1&post_name=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please tell me if it works.

---

Moreover if you only want to redirect *only* deal-info, you should do something like (not tested):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(/)?deal-info/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /deal-info/?id=$2&post_name=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

May I ask you to add the rewritelog in your question?

Comment: You rock mate. i cant tell how many "explanations" i have read today ;)

Comment: just one caveat in Wordpress the .htaccess file can be rewritten by PHP and you may loose your changes, use the rewrite api instead... good luck