# php get variable clean url htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have some custom PHP pages I am using with a WordPress site. I'd like to use clean URLs which have a couple of variables via the GET method. I have searched and tried different variations of my htaccess code in combination with the WordPress htaccess code below without success.

I would like the URL that users browse to and use to be www.thedomain.com/thefolder/details/123456/RES, instead of www.thedomain.com/thefolder/details.php?mls=123456&ret=RES

I've put my code in the htaccess file in the root directory. I have also tried it on its own in a htaccess in the directory where the details.php file is located.

```
RewriteEngine On

## WordPress code
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]

## my code
RewriteBase /thefolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ details.php?mls=$1&ret=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ details.php?mls=$1&ret=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add QSA to the RewriteRule flags:

RewriteRule {from-url} {to-url} [L,NC,QSA]

```
RewriteRule page_([0-9]+)\.html page.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Will redirect page_1.html?a=2 to page.php?id=1&a=2

However, be careful because requesting page_1.html?id=2 will redirect to page.php?id=1&id=2, and (in PHP), $_GET['id'] will be 2.

Comment: _Will redirect page_1.html?a=2..._ - are you sure `RewriteRule` _redirects_?

Comment: Test it out then if it doesn't work you give feedback about your experience. That way we can tackle the redirection until it works fine

Comment: Hey I wanted to say that `RewriteRule` does not redirect, it just rewrites the url.

Comment: You mean it rewrites but doesn't call up the required page or you want the page redirected to a different page. Please clear me on this. Thanks

Comment: @OmniPotens - tried your suggestion of adding [QSA] to the end of both RewriteRule lines, but it did not work. When trying to browse to www.thedomain.com/thefolder/details/123456/RES, I get page not found error.

Comment: Can you post the URL you are trying to redirect please?

Comment: URL I would like users to use - www.galerealestate.ca/listings/details/859862/RES. URL they are currently using - www.galerealestate.ca/listings/details.php?mls=859862&ret=RES

Comment: Here is what I ended up using:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^listings/([A-Z]?[0-9]{6,9})/([a-z]{3})/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ /listings/details.php?mls=$1&ret=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]

Based on Olivier Pons answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476654/add-url-rewrite-rule-to-wordpress