# htaccess: How to redirect non-www url to my www-url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Currently my site can only be visited when visiting www.mysite.net or http://www.mysite.net. How can I change this so that when one just visits http://mysite.net, that you will be directed to www.mysite.net?

Here is my current HTACCESS file content

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also tried this...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %mysite.net !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.%mysite.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159088/how-to-modify-htaccess-file-to-always-redirect-to-www?rq=1

Comment: The top ruleset should work, but you may need to move `RewriteBase` to to just after `RewriteEngine On`. What happens when you try that ruleset?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**edit:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**edit 2**

[Add URL Rewrite Rule To Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476654/add-url-rewrite-rule-to-wordpress) this is not helpful?

Comment: for some reason it still does not work. Maybe Wordpress is messing it up...I am going to update the question with my actual htaccess file

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476654/add-url-rewrite-rule-to-wordpress

Answer (score -1):

You Must Use This Code In htaccess File To Preferred www Version:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.).YourDomain.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.)$ http://www.YourDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]